# Not all updates can be installed (missing packages)

Tags: 10.10, update-manager, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and the update manager claims that not all updates can be installed.

I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and got this:

> Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg Ign
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US 
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
>   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/banshee-daily/ubuntu/
>   maverick/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/banshee-daily/ubuntu/
>   maverick/main Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release.gpg
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe
>   Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main
>   Translation-en_US
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe
>   Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
>   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main
>   Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
>   Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner
>   Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main
>   Translation-en_US
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe
>   Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe
>   Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release
>   Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
>   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://linux.dropbox.com maverick Release.gpg
>   Ign http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages 
>   Ign http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://linux.dropbox.com maverick Release
>   Get:1 ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Release.gpg
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
>   Hit http://linux.dropbox.com maverick/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
>   Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
>   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release                      Hit
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages
>   Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages
>   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                 Ign
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Release.gpg                       Ign
>   http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/
>   all/main Translation-en Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main
>   i386 Packages Ign
>   http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/
>   all/main Translation-en_US Get:2
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/ stable/ Translation-en
>   Hit http://downloads.sourceforge.net all Release.gpg Ign
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/ stable/ Translation-en
>   Get:3 ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/ stable/
>   Translation-en_US Hit http://downloads.sourceforge.net all Release
>   Ign http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main i386 Packages Ign
>   http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main i386 Packages Ign
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/ stable/
>   Translation-en_US Get:4 ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Release
>   Hit http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main i386 Packages Ign
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Release Get:5 ftp://ftp.berlios.de
>   stable/ Packages Ign ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Packages Get:6
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Packages Ign ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/
>   Packages Get:7 ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Packages Err
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de stable/ Packages   Unable to fetch file, server
>   said '/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/stable/Packages.gz: No such file or
>   directory  ' W: Failed to fetch
>   ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/stable/Packages.gz 
>   Unable to fetch file, server said
>   '/pub/yajhfc/repository/apt/stable/Packages.gz: No such file or
>   directory  '
>
> E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

I'm using the main repository and have unchecked multiverse and restricted. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have enabled a repository that it cannot find.

To fix this, do the following:

- Open up the software sources configuration dialog (Press the ALT+F1 key, type "Software sources" and run the program that appears)
- Choose the "Other sources" tab, and scroll down the list until you find the repository named "ftp.berlios.de"
- Uncheck the repository (or delete it)

Press "Close" and select to refresh the software list when prompted.